# Why is my string length function not returning length?

Tags: c++, string, object, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class String {
    public:
        String(); 
        String(const char []); 
        String(const String &); 
        int Compare(const String &) const; 
        int Compare(const char[]) const;
        String & Copy(const String &); 
        String & Copy(const char[]); 
        size_t Len() const; 
        String & Conc(const char[]);
        String & Conc(const String &);
        String Display() const;

    private:
        size_t Letters;
        size_t Slots;
        char* Fazah;
    };

    String::String() {
        Letters = 0;
        Slots = Letters;
        Fazah = new char [Slots + 1];
        Fazah[0]= '\0';
    }

    String::String(const char otherVar[]) { 
        Letters = strlen(otherVar);
        Slots = Letters;
        Fazah = new char [Slots + 1];
        strcpy(Fazah, otherVar);
    }

    String::String(const String & otherVar) {
        Slots = otherVar.Slots;
        Letters = otherVar.Letters;
        Fazah = new char [Slots + 1];
        strcpy (Fazah, otherVar.Fazah);
        cout  <<"Copy const"<< endl;
    }

    int String::Compare (const String & otherVar) const {
        return strcmp (Fazah, otherVar.Fazah);
    }

    int String::Compare(const char otherVar []) const {
        return strcmp (Fazah, otherVar);
    }

    inline size_t String::Len ()const {
        return Letters;
    }

    String String::Display() const {
        return* this;
    }

    String & String::Copy(const String & otherVar) {
        delete[] Fazah;
        Letters = otherVar.Letters;
        Slots = otherVar.Letters;
        Fazah = new char [Slots + 1];
        return *this;
    }

    String & String::Copy(const char otherVar []) {
        delete[] Fazah;
        Letters = strlen (otherVar);
        Slots = Letters;
        Fazah = new char [Slots + 1];
        return *this;;
    }

    String & String::Conc(const String & otherVar) {
        //delete[] Fazah;
        Letters = Letters + otherVar.Letters;
        Slots = Slots + otherVar.Slots;
        Fazah = new char [Slots + 1 ];
        return*this;
    }

    String & String::Conc(const char otherVal[]) {
        Slots = Slots + Letters;
        Letters = Letters + strlen(otherVal);
        Fazah = new char [Slots + 1];
        return* this;
    }

    int main() {
        String Str2("abcdefg");
        String Len(Str2);
    }
```

I've been learning c++ for a few weeks now so I'm still relatively new at this. there's been these times where i'm just not sure what to look up to fix my issue, this is one of those times. This is not even a syntax error so it makes it more difficult to fix. 
This is probably because I'm still quite new at this; in my head `String Len(Str2)` should return the length of the string, but it doesn't it only returns the `cout  <<"Copy const"<< endl`  . Not really sure what to do here.

Comment: All that statement does is create a second variable named `Len`, it doesn't call the `Len` method at all.

Comment: `#include <string>` is for `std::string`, perhaps you meant to `#include <cstring>` directly for the C string functions? Also, why using `std` if you don't have any code using the `std` library (and also should not have that in an include file if that is where this code is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
String Len(Str2);
```

creates another instance of `String`. It does not call the `Len` member function. You need to use:

```
size_t len = Str2.Len();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you call a member function.

`String Len(Str2);` means that you are just creating another `String` by the name of `Len`, to which the contents of `Str2` will be copied, when the copy constructor `String::String (const String & otherVar)`, that you have written will be called.

You should use `Str2.Len()`to call the appropriate member function `inline size_t String::Len ()const` that you have written.

Then you should use `cout` to print it on the console:

```
std::cout<<Str2.Len();
```

Answer (score 0):

To print it out, in `main`, change:

```
String Len(Str2);
```

Into:

```
std::cout << Str2.Len() << std::endl;
```